# How to get Firebase Storage image URL in android studio?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to display image on imageView from Firebase Storage without saving the picture in the device, so I've tried to use the highlighted URL (from the photo below) and it works but I don't want to write the address manually.
How can I get the address using the code?
p.s I tried dataBaseStorageRef.getDownloadUrl() and it gives me another URL, not the one from the picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgRnj.png)

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    final StorageReference filePath = storage.child("books").child(""+AddBook.book_id+1).child("photo.jpg");
    if(requestCode == RESULT_GALLERY){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            pic_uri = data.getData();
            book_img.setImageURI(pic_uri);
            filePath.putFile(pic_uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Toast.makeText(AddBookActivity.this, "Upload done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(AddBookActivity.this, "Failed to upload!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
            img_addr = filePath.getDownloadUrl().toString();


            Toast.makeText(this, "picture was selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I'm trying to display the pic from img_addr from another activity
and it doesn't work because the address of image_addr is not good (if I replace manually img_addr to the address from the attached link it works)

```
    if(books_list.get(i).img_addr!=null){
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),books_list.get(i).img_addr,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Picasso.with(v.getContext()).load(books_list.get(i).img_addr).resize(50,50).into(img);

    }
```

Thanks to those who help

Comment: Can you provide the code you tried and your screenshot of your database?

Answer (score 0):

Make `getDownloadUrl()` asynchronous by adding onsuccess and onfailure listeners to it.

Your complete image upload task should look like below

```
 photoReference.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                photoReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                       //do something
                    }
                }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        //get your image uri here
                        Uri imgUrl = uri;
                        String imgStringUrl = imgUrl.toString();
                    }
                });

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
               // do something
            }
        });
```

Comment: It is different from what you did.

Comment: Add a success listener to  filePath.getDownloadUrl() and retrieve the url from the listener like in my code . Your call is synchronous and there is no guarantee that the url would be retrieved immediately. That is why the call should be asynchronous. Get the download url from the success listener

Answer (score 0):

You can use `continueWithTask` method to return the download url

Like the following:

```
final UploadTask uploadTask = filepath.putFile(uri);   
uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                                        uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                    throw task.getException();

                                                }
                                                // Continue with the task to get the download URL
                                                return filepath.getDownloadUrl();

                                            }
                                        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                    thumb_download_url = task.getResult().toString();


                                                }
                                            }
                                        });

                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    }
                                });
```

Comment: The URL address of getDownloadUrl is not working for me. I've added my code, please check

Comment: Use the code i provided. `continueWithTask` will help you to return the url when upload is finished. Your code is wrong! this `img_addr = filePath.getDownloadUrl().toString();` should be inside `oncompleteListener`.  USe the code i provided. the downloaded url is `thumb_download_url = task.getResult().toString();` in my case. Just rename it to `img_addr`, that is all

Answer (score 0):

You can get download URL from below method:

```
private void uploadToStorage(String imgPath, String fileName) {

    Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File(imgPath));
    StorageReference storageReference = mStorageRef.child(userId + "/images/" + fileName);

    storageReference.putFile(file).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Task<Uri> downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
            downloadUrl.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Media is uploaded");

                    String downloadURL = "https://" + task.getResult().getEncodedAuthority() 
                            + task.getResult().getEncodedPath() 
                            + "?alt=media&token=" 
                            + task.getResult().getQueryParameters("token").get(0);

                    Log.v(TAG, "downloadURL: " + downloadURL);
                    //save your downloadURL
                }
            });
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Media is not uploaded");
            Log.v(TAG, "Exception: " + exception.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

You can also get scheme name & query from methods under `task.getResult()`